# Conversion html to Visualforce - Javascripts not running

Tags: visualforce, javascript, html

I converted html pages to visual force and referenced all used elements (css, javascript, pictures) as Static Resources. Within the code I see which javascripts are being used. However, when I try to run them, they do not work. What could be the problem here? One file is very complex and unstructured, so it is not easy to work with it. It seems as if the objects on the page cannot be found properly. Is there any advice on that? Thank you!

PS: There is no error in the console.

I convert the references as below:

script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min‌​.js">

into:

apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.xxx_js, 'xxx_js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js')}" />

script>window.jQuery || document.write('</script>')

into:

script>window.jQuery || document.write('</script>‌​')

And I have two more libraries,

apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.xxx_js, 'xxx_js/carousel.js')}" />

and

apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.xxx_js, 'xxx_js/main.js')}" />

There is one weird reaction, when I include the script "main.js", some elements get displaced. The script main.js only contains two functions though, function toggleMenu() {} and $(document).ready(function() {$("#xxx-carousel").xxxCarousel({ }); }); The xxx.carousel function then seems to relate to the carousel.js...

Comment: Visualforce itself has a lot of JS. One of the directions may be check if there are conflicts with VF code. But before -- confirm that all JS has been loaded properly

Comment: Also, let us know if you see any errors in the browser console(press F12).

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we found the answer, I copied the code from the Chrome developer tools. It seems that there was additional code added by Javascript. As we got the original html code, we could clear the additions which got the code running.